# C# .Net API Post Call Using HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] is always null

Tags: c#, xml

I'm new to writing .net APIs and I'm working in Visual Studio 2017. I've been working on this for a couple of days and I'm completely stumped.  I'm trying to create a simple web API that a Post call sends a cXML string passed into it via the Post Body.  I then take the incoming cXML string and simply save it to a text file on a network drive.  That is all I need to do, I don't need to de-serialize the XML, read any of the fields or extract any data out of the XML, I just need to grab the entire input XML string and save it to a text file.  The problem I'm having is no matter what I've tried the incoming body always seems to be null.  My code is simple:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Pass_XML_to_File")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] dynamic IncomingXML)
        {
        //do work here: take Incoming xml string and save it to a file which should be simple...
        }
```

Unfortunately my `IncomingXML` variable is always null, so I have no data to save into a text file.  I've been testing this from Postman and no matter what I've tried the variable is always null.

I've tried many other ways such as

```
Post([FromBody] XmlDocument IncomingXML)
Post([FromBody] string IncomingXML), etc.
```

I've tried changing in Content-Type header in Postman from application/xml, text/xml, text and a few others without any success.  The funny thing is if I pass a JSON string in the body (changing the Content-Type to text/JSON) the data comes in perfectly without issue.  Just when I pass XML the incoming body is always null.

Does anyone know how I can get the body XML to come in as a string so I can simply save it to a text file for later processing on a separate system?

Comment: Don't use `dynamic` for this. There's basically no legitimate reason for ever using `dynamic` in C#, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the form you sent on the client side?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Pass_XML_to_File")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] dynamic IncomingXML)
{
  // data is coming in correctly.
  return null;
}
```

Postman Client Send :

```
{
    "IncomingXML":"<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don'tforgetmethisweekend!</body></note>"
}
```

data comes to variable successfully.

Comment: Thank you Oguzhan here is what Postman Client is sending:
 
POST http://localhost:61924/api/Pass_XML_to_BOOMI
200
21.89 s
Network
Request Headers
x-api-key: abc
Content-Type: application/xml
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: b534793b-3160-40d9-92ac-9d35042be718
Host: localhost:61924
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 170
Request Body
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

Answer (score 0):

if you want to accept a xml format request, you should do the below steps:
Startup.ConfigureServices edit:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); 
}
```

Apply the Consumes attribute to controller classes or action methods that should expect XML in the request body.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Pass_XML_to_File")]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] dynamic IncomingXML)
{

  // data is coming in correctly.
  return null;
}
```

Note: Install the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml** NuGet package.

Comment: I added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml NuGet package but unfortunately when trying to add 

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); 
}

to the startup.cs it is underlining in red AddControllers() with the error "iServiceCollection does not contain a definition for 'AddControllers.  grrrrrr

Answer (score 0):

Please **XmlDocument** instead of **dynamic** as it will work. Then you can manipulate the request in the business loggic

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Pass_XML_to_File")]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] XmlDocument IncomingXML)
{

  // data is coming in correctly.
  return null;
}
```